# Restarting Main Thread in IOS

Tags: ios, multithreading

I have an application/game which I am adding a restart button to. The easiest thing for me to do this is if there was a bit of code which would release all objects created by the app running and restart the main thread (there are many of them including timers which may be running when the reset button is being pressed).

Is there any such code?

I understand that it may be possible to run the app in a secondary thread and refresh that but I dont have any threading experience.

can anyone help?

Comment: By halting the execution of the main thread, you are seriously considering completely stopping graphics and sound as well.  Are you sure there is absolutely no other way than this?  And besides, threads don't control the aspects of your classes and data types, they don't "reset", they just start and stop.

Comment: Ill rephrase the question in that is there anyway I can redraw or refresh the main view?

Comment: Yes.  Set everything back the way it was.  Don't release and instantiate, invalidate and reset.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing i know is you can force kill your app but be prepared as it will be rejected by apple and even if you get success in killing app then you cannot restart it.

Comment: Zynga does this (though I suspect they have a cozy relationship with apple anyhow) all the time.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to *restart the main thread* or anything similar. You're probably thinking of the wrong design. Think of it from an object oriented perspective: what you need to do is to **restore the state of some objects** that keep track of the state of your application.
So say you have a `Game` class that has some properties like:

- level
- points

what you'd have to do is restore those to 0 (or whatever the initial value is).

Hope you get the idea ;)

Comment: I thought as much but my problem is when there is an array of nstimers queued and the reset button is pressed that array is being invalidated while another array is being instantiaed on the same UI objects

Comment: Why not just wait for the execution of the invalidation loop to finish.  You seriously risk having accessing a dangling pointer and having this thing go down if you don't.

Comment: I think "dangling pointer" perfectly describes what I am experiencing

Answer (score 1):

there is not easy way to do that, if you want to restart the game or level you will have to recreate the level, by re assign the level variables redrawing the correct components etc..., you will not be able to restart the game or level by restarting a thread,